# Change gestureHandling in Leaflet when map is already initalized

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet fo implement a map in my website. 
I use the feature **gestureHandling** to make sure that scrolling is not captured by the map. Everything works fine - but I would like to change the **gestureHandling** attribute later in the code when a user choses to make the map fullscreen.

I can't get it to work. Do I have to reinitialise the map somehow?

Thanks in advance!

This is my Code:

```
map = L.map($map[0], {
    center: new L.LatLng(47, 10),
    zoom: 14,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
    layers: [layerGroup],
    gestureHandling: true
});

$('body').on('click','.resize-toggler',function(){
    map.gestureHandling = false;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The following code works.
There seems to be a function you can call -> **map.gestureHandling.disable();**

```
map = L.map($map[0], {
    center: new L.LatLng(47, 10),
    zoom: 14,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
    layers: [layerGroup],
    gestureHandling: true
});

$('body').on('click','.resize-toggler',function(){
    map.gestureHandling.disable();
})
```